# Using Mailmerge to sort a list by Category

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I followed this support article from microsoft:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294686/en-us#2

I seem to be missing something as the output does not list properly per city.

I get a single line per preview, not the entire list per city as I expected.

Is there anyone here who has experience having this work properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mail Merge - Multiple Rows Into One Document](http://superuser.com/questions/680211/mail-merge-multiple-rows-into-one-document)

Answer (score 1):

Preview only displays data from one record (or from one record + as many records as you have NEXT fields, roughly speaking. In fact Preview can mislead in other ways, too.)

To see the list you will need to complete the merge, e.g. actually merge to a new document.

[macropod's tutorial](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/111149) has a better description of how to do one-many merges just using fields, but I think you will need to subscribe to the windowssecrets site to get it.

Other approaches include:

A Word [addin](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5aedcb43615e886b#!/?cid=5AEDCB43615E886B!cid=5AEDCB43615E886B&id=5AEDCB43615E886B!566) (template) by Doug Robbins

A Word [addin](http://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm) by Graham Mayor