# Word 2007 Merge Document - creating only one letter to recipient for multiple records

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

- Record 1:  Mary Smith, Barney
- Record 2:  Mary Smith, Pebbles
- Record 3:  Mary Smith , BamBam
- Record 4:  Bill Shoe, Rocky

For example, Mary Smith is listed in my database 3 times with 3 different dogs.  When I merge I get 3 letters to Mary each referencing 1 dog, before it moves to the 4th record.

Can I put in code so Word knows to merge each of the 3 entries into 1 letter for Mary referring to her 3 dogs?

Comment: see my reply to http://superuser.com/questions/621212/using-mailmerge-to-sort-a-list-by-category/621420#621420